# Kafka Burrow stopped after running for a while

Tags: apache-kafka

I try to monitor consumer lag in Kafka with [Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow). I could get the result from HTTP endpoint, but it's only for a while. After about one minute, I couldn't get any response from burrow and port 8000 is closed.

I have my zookeeper installed in same host with kafka instance. Here my configuration and error log.

**burrow.cfg**

```
[general]
logdir=log
logconfig=config/logging.cfg
pidfile=burrow.pid
client-id=burrow-lagchecker
group-blacklist=^(console-consumer-|python-kafka-consumer-).*$

[zookeeper]
hostname=kafka01
hostname=kafka02
hostname=kafka03
port=2181
timeout=6
lock-path=/burrow/notifier

[kafka "TestEnvironment"]
broker=kafka01
broker=kafka02
broker=kafka03
broker-port=6667
zookeeper=kafka01
zookeeper=kafka02
zookeeper=kafka03
zookeeper-port=2181
zookeeper-path=/kafka-cluster
offsets-topic=__consumer_offsets

[tickers]
broker-offsets=60

[lagcheck]
intervals=10
expire-group=604800

[httpserver]
server=on
port=8000

[smtp]
server=mailserver.example.com
port=25
from=burrow-noreply@example.com
template=config/default-email.tmpl

[email "bofh@example.com"]
group=local,critical-consumer-group
group=local,other-consumer-group
interval=60

[httpnotifier]
url=http://notification.server.example.com:9000/v1/alert
interval=60
extra=app=burrow
extra=tier=STG
template-post=config/default-http-post.tmpl
template-delete=config/default-http-delete.tmpl
```

**burrow.log**

```
2015-09-16 06:02:28 [INFO] Starting Zookeeper client
2015-09-16 06:02:28 [INFO] Starting Offsets Storage module
2015-09-16 06:02:28 [INFO] Starting HTTP server
2015-09-16 06:02:28 [INFO] Starting Zookeeper client for cluster TestEnvironment
2015-09-16 06:02:28 [INFO] Starting Kafka client for cluster TestEnvironment
2015-09-16 06:02:28 [INFO] Starting consumers for 1 partitions of __consumer_offsets in cluster TestEnvironment
2015-09-16 06:02:28 [INFO] Configuring Email notifier
2015-09-16 06:02:28 [INFO] Configuring HTTP notifier
2015-09-16 06:02:28 [INFO] Acquired Zookeeper notifier lock
2015-09-16 06:02:28 [INFO] Starting Email notifier
2015-09-16 06:02:28 [INFO] Starting HTTP notifier
```

**burrow.out**

```
Started Burrow at September 16, 2015 at 6:02am (UTC)
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x4172e2]

goroutine 183 [running]:
main.(*OffsetStorage).evaluateGroup(0xc8201d95c0, 0xc8200e00c0, 0x5, 0xc8200e00c6, 0x17, 0xc8204545a0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/offsets_store.go:337 +0x182
created by main.NewOffsetStorage.func1
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/offsets_store.go:188 +0x43f

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.burrowMain(0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/main.go:194 +0x1c2b
main.main()
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/main.go:200 +0x33

goroutine 17 [syscall, 1 minutes, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1

goroutine 5 [semacquire, 1 minutes]:
sync.runtime_Syncsemacquire(0xc820019150)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:237 +0x201
sync.(*Cond).Wait(0xc820019140)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/cond.go:62 +0x9b
github.com/cihub/seelog.(*asyncLoopLogger).processItem(0xc82001c600, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:50 +0xc7
github.com/cihub/seelog.(*asyncLoopLogger).processQueue(0xc82001c600)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:63 +0x2a
created by github.com/cihub/seelog.newAsyncLoopLogger
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:40 +0x91

goroutine 6 [semacquire, 1 minutes]:
sync.runtime_Syncsemacquire(0xc8200192d0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:237 +0x201
sync.(*Cond).Wait(0xc8200192c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/cond.go:62 +0x9b
github.com/cihub/seelog.(*asyncLoopLogger).processItem(0xc82001c720, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:50 +0xc7
github.com/cihub/seelog.(*asyncLoopLogger).processQueue(0xc82001c720)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:63 +0x2a
created by github.com/cihub/seelog.newAsyncLoopLogger
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:40 +0x91

goroutine 7 [syscall, 1 minutes]:
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x18
created by os/signal.init.1
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x37

goroutine 8 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Syncsemacquire(0xc820316710)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:237 +0x201
sync.(*Cond).Wait(0xc820316700)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/cond.go:62 +0x9b
github.com/cihub/seelog.(*asyncLoopLogger).processItem(0xc8200dd800, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:50 +0xc7
github.com/cihub/seelog.(*asyncLoopLogger).processQueue(0xc8200dd800)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:63 +0x2a
created by github.com/cihub/seelog.newAsyncLoopLogger
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:40 +0x91

goroutine 9 [semacquire, 1 minutes]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc82079201c)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:43 +0x26
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc820792010)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:126 +0xb4
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).loop(0xc820069e10)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:227 +0x671
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.ConnectWithDialer.func1(0xc820069e10)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:145 +0x21
created by github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.ConnectWithDialer
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:149 +0x452

goroutine 10 [select]:
main.NewOffsetStorage.func1(0xc8201d95c0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/offsets_store.go:168 +0x4a8
created by main.NewOffsetStorage
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/offsets_store.go:199 +0x4b7

goroutine 11 [IO wait]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x7f17dc7d8fb0, 0x72, 0xc820010190)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x60
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc8203b6060, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x3a
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc8203b6060, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78 +0x36
net.(*netFD).accept(0xc8203b6000, 0x0, 0x7f17dc7d90a8, 0xc8200e1c80)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:408 +0x27c
net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP(0xc8203d8000, 0x46e890, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:254 +0x4d
net/http.tcpKeepAliveListener.Accept(0xc8203d8000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2135 +0x41
net/http.(*Server).Serve(0xc82038a000, 0x7f17dc7d9070, 0xc8203d8000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1887 +0xb3
net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe(0xc82038a000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1877 +0x136
net/http.ListenAndServe(0xc820338750, 0x5, 0x7f17db9a02e8, 0xc8201d97a0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1967 +0x8f
created by main.NewHttpServer
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/http_server.go:49 +0x4f7

goroutine 12 [semacquire, 1 minutes]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc8204460cc)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:43 +0x26
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc8204460c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:126 +0xb4
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).loop(0xc82034a000)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:227 +0x671
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.ConnectWithDialer.func1(0xc82034a000)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:145 +0x21
created by github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.ConnectWithDialer
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:149 +0x452

goroutine 35 [runnable]:
github.com/Shopify/sarama.decode(0xc82035e2a0, 0x8, 0x8, 0x7f17db9a4428, 0xc8200ca3d0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/encoder_decoder.go:51 +0x69
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).responseReceiver(0xc820318930)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:354 +0x3e0
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).(github.com/Shopify/sarama.responseReceiver)-fm()
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:93 +0x20
github.com/Shopify/sarama.withRecover(0xc8204220c0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/utils.go:42 +0x3a
created by github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).Open.func1
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:93 +0x59b

goroutine 16 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*client).backgroundMetadataUpdater(0xc8200b1600)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/client.go:553 +0x322
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*client).(github.com/Shopify/sarama.backgroundMetadataUpdater)-fm()
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/client.go:142 +0x20
github.com/Shopify/sarama.withRecover(0xc82041d470)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/utils.go:42 +0x3a
created by github.com/Shopify/sarama.NewClient
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/client.go:142 +0x754

goroutine 34 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).responseReceiver(0xc820318690)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:340 +0xf6
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).(github.com/Shopify/sarama.responseReceiver)-fm()
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:93 +0x20
github.com/Shopify/sarama.withRecover(0xc820422050)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/utils.go:42 +0x3a
created by github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).Open.func1
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:93 +0x59b

goroutine 50 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
main.NewKafkaClient.func1(0xc8200166e0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:78 +0x8f
created by main.NewKafkaClient
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:81 +0x43a

goroutine 51 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
main.NewKafkaClient.func2(0xc8200166e0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:84 +0x95
created by main.NewKafkaClient
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:87 +0x45c

goroutine 52 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
main.NewKafkaClient.func3(0xc8200166e0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:92 +0x4e
created by main.NewKafkaClient
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:95 +0x48c

goroutine 38 [select]:
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*brokerConsumer).subscriptionManager(0xc820432550)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:547 +0x3e7
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*brokerConsumer).(github.com/Shopify/sarama.subscriptionManager)-fm()
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:520 +0x20
github.com/Shopify/sarama.withRecover(0xc8204222c0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/utils.go:42 +0x3a
created by github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*consumer).newBrokerConsumer
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:520 +0x200

goroutine 21 [select]:
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).sendLoop(0xc82034a000, 0x7f17db9a43a0, 0xc8203d8008, 0xc820448300, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:412 +0xd8b
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).loop.func1(0xc82034a000, 0xc820448300, 0xc8204460c0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:212 +0x48
created by github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).loop
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:215 +0x609

goroutine 23 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc8202e821c)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:43 +0x26
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc8202e8210)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:126 +0xb4
main.(*KafkaClient).getOffsets(0xc8200166e0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:228 +0x7a5
main.NewKafkaClient.func4(0xc8200166e0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:102 +0x75
created by main.NewKafkaClient
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:104 +0x508

goroutine 36 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*partitionConsumer).dispatcher(0xc820778000)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:295 +0x57
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*partitionConsumer).(github.com/Shopify/sarama.dispatcher)-fm()
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:151 +0x20
github.com/Shopify/sarama.withRecover(0xc8204222a0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/utils.go:42 +0x3a
created by github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*consumer).ConsumePartition
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:151 +0x454

goroutine 37 [chan receive]:
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*partitionConsumer).responseFeeder(0xc820778000)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:403 +0x5d
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*partitionConsumer).(github.com/Shopify/sarama.responseFeeder)-fm()
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:152 +0x20
github.com/Shopify/sarama.withRecover(0xc8204222b0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/utils.go:42 +0x3a
created by github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*consumer).ConsumePartition
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:152 +0x4ab

goroutine 67 [chan receive]:
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).responseReceiver(0xc8203188c0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:340 +0xf6
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).(github.com/Shopify/sarama.responseReceiver)-fm()
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:93 +0x20
github.com/Shopify/sarama.withRecover(0xc8203ac0a0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/utils.go:42 +0x3a
created by github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).Open.func1
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:93 +0x59b

goroutine 20 [chan receive]:
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).responseReceiver(0xc820318850)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:340 +0xf6
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).(github.com/Shopify/sarama.responseReceiver)-fm()
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:93 +0x20
github.com/Shopify/sarama.withRecover(0xc820446060)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/utils.go:42 +0x3a
created by github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).Open.func1
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:93 +0x59b

goroutine 22 [IO wait]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x7f17dc7d8e30, 0x72, 0xc820010190)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x60
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc8203b60d0, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x3a
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc8203b60d0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78 +0x36
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc8203b6070, 0xc82045e000, 0x4, 0x180000, 0x0, 0x7f17db997050, 0xc820010190)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:232 +0x23a
net.(*conn).Read(0xc8203d8008, 0xc82045e000, 0x4, 0x180000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:172 +0xe4
io.ReadAtLeast(0x7f17d8150160, 0xc8203d8008, 0xc82045e000, 0x4, 0x180000, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:298 +0xe6
io.ReadFull(0x7f17d8150160, 0xc8203d8008, 0xc82045e000, 0x4, 0x180000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:316 +0x62
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).recvLoop(0xc82034a000, 0x7f17db9a43a0, 0xc8203d8008, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:476 +0x231
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).loop.func2(0xc8203ac030, 0xc82034a000, 0xc820448300, 0xc8204460c0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:219 +0x46
created by github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).loop
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:225 +0x663

goroutine 100 [chan receive]:
main.NewKafkaClient.func6(0xc8200166e0, 0x7f17d80d1000, 0xc820778000)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:130 +0x9f
created by main.NewKafkaClient
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:133 +0xae8

goroutine 99 [chan receive]:
main.NewKafkaClient.func5(0xc8200166e0, 0x7f17d80d1000, 0xc820778000)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:124 +0x9f
created by main.NewKafkaClient
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:127 +0xaac

goroutine 107 [select]:
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).sendAndReceive(0xc820318930, 0x7f17db9a46a0, 0xc8203b8390, 0x7f17db9a46e0, 0xc8203d8270, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:286 +0x23f
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).GetAvailableOffsets(0xc820318930, 0xc8203b8390, 0xc800000002, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:174 +0xc1
main.(*KafkaClient).getOffsets.func1(0xc800000002, 0xc8203b8390)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:198 +0xa1
created by main.(*KafkaClient).getOffsets
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/kafka_client.go:225 +0x770

goroutine 144 [select, locked to thread]:
runtime.gopark(0x9ea3c8, 0xc8203be728, 0x913530, 0x6, 0x18, 0x2)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:185 +0x163
runtime.selectgoImpl(0xc8203be728, 0x0, 0x18)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/select.go:392 +0xa64
runtime.selectgo(0xc8203be728)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/select.go:212 +0x12
runtime.ensureSigM.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal1_unix.go:227 +0x353
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1

goroutine 145 [chan receive]:
main.(*Emailer).sendEmailNotifications(0xc820416420, 0xc8200e0080, 0x10, 0x910828, 0x7, 0xc8200e01a0, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc820796720)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/emailer.go:116 +0x45e
created by main.(*Emailer).Start
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/emailer.go:59 +0x1da

goroutine 162 [select]:
main.(*HttpNotifier).Start.func1(0xc820316940)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/http_notifier.go:197 +0x19b
created by main.(*HttpNotifier).Start
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/http_notifier.go:207 +0x7a

goroutine 146 [select]:
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).sendLoop(0xc820069e10, 0x7f17db9a43a0, 0xc8200322b8, 0xc820796000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:412 +0xd8b
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).loop.func1(0xc820069e10, 0xc820796000, 0xc820792010)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:212 +0x48
created by github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).loop
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:215 +0x609

goroutine 147 [IO wait]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x7f17dc7d8ef0, 0x72, 0xc820010190)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x60
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc820318840, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x3a
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc820318840, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78 +0x36
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc8203187e0, 0xc8207a6000, 0x4, 0x180000, 0x0, 0x7f17db997050, 0xc820010190)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:232 +0x23a
net.(*conn).Read(0xc8200322b8, 0xc8207a6000, 0x4, 0x180000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:172 +0xe4
io.ReadAtLeast(0x7f17d8150160, 0xc8200322b8, 0xc8207a6000, 0x4, 0x180000, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:298 +0xe6
io.ReadFull(0x7f17d8150160, 0xc8200322b8, 0xc8207a6000, 0x4, 0x180000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:316 +0x62
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).recvLoop(0xc820069e10, 0x7f17db9a43a0, 0xc8200322b8, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:476 +0x231
github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).loop.func2(0xc82041cb80, 0xc820069e10, 0xc820796000, 0xc820792010)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:219 +0x46
created by github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).loop
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:225 +0x663

goroutine 39 [select]:
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).sendAndReceive(0xc820318930, 0x7f17d8090100, 0xc820338380, 0x7f17d8090140, 0xc820382360, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:286 +0x23f
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*Broker).Fetch(0xc820318930, 0xc820338380, 0xc82003fd94, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/broker.go:204 +0xc1
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*brokerConsumer).fetchNewMessages(0xc820432550, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:646 +0x34e
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*brokerConsumer).subscriptionConsumer(0xc820432550)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:580 +0x144
github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*brokerConsumer).(github.com/Shopify/sarama.subscriptionConsumer)-fm()
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:521 +0x20
github.com/Shopify/sarama.withRecover(0xc8204222d0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/utils.go:42 +0x3a
created by github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*consumer).newBrokerConsumer
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/consumer.go:521 +0x253

goroutine 184 [runnable]:
main.(*OffsetStorage).evaluateGroup(0xc8201d95c0, 0xc8200e0160, 0x5, 0xc8200e0166, 0x14, 0xc8204545a0)
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/offsets_store.go:337 +0x182
created by main.NewOffsetStorage.func1
    /home/dwirawan/work/src/github.com/linkedin/burrow/offsets_store.go:188 +0x43f
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issues is due to kafka cluster. Check your kafka cluster was properly running or Not .The NPE is because Burrow is unable to start the consumers for the __consumer_offsets topic. This could be due to ACL issues, or because the topic doesn't exist yet (it's only created after the first consumer group is started up).